# Hadoop - Result of WordCount is not writing on output file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a program to count the number of words with their frequency by following the steps given in this link: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html

I've loaded one directory named ***input*** which includes three text files.

I was able to configure everything correctly. Now while the running the WordCount.java, I don't see anything in **part-00000** file inside output directory.

The java code for Mapper is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class WordCountMapper extends MapReduceBase
implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(WritableComparable key, Writable value,
  OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

String line = value.toString();
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line.toLowerCase());
while(itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
  word.set(itr.nextToken());
  output.collect(word, one);
}
}

@Override
public void map(LongWritable arg0, Text arg1,
    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> arg2, Reporter arg3)
     throws IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

}
```

The reduce code is:

```
public class WordCountReducer extends MapReduceBase
implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterator values,
  OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

int sum = 0;
while (values.hasNext()) {
    //System.out.println(values.next());
  IntWritable value = (IntWritable) values.next();
  sum += value.get(); // process value
}

output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
 }
 }
```

The code for Word counter is:

```
public class Counter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobClient client = new JobClient();
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(com.example.Counter.class);

    // TODO: specify output types
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // TODO: specify input and output DIRECTORIES (not files)
    conf.setInputPath(new Path("src"));
    conf.setOutputPath(new Path("out"));

    // TODO: specify a mapper
    conf.setMapperClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.class);

    // TODO: specify a reducer
    conf
                   .setReducerClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer.class);

    client.setConf(conf);
    try {
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

In console I get these logs:

```
13/09/10 10:09:20 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the       arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/09/10 10:09:20 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
13/09/10 10:09:20 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
13/09/10 10:09:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201309100855_0012
13/09/10 10:09:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/09/10 10:09:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 25% reduce 0%
13/09/10 10:09:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 75% reduce 0%
13/09/10 10:09:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201309100855_0012
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 15
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Systems
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS bytes read=54049
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Local bytes read=14
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Local bytes written=214
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=326
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=50752
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
13/09/10 10:09:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
```

I'm pretty new in Hadoop.

Kindly reply with appropriate answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show me your code?Your job is reading the input but it is not emitting anything.

Comment: @Tariq I've edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Delete the second **map()** and re-run your job. I would also suggest you to use the new API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `map` methods in your Mapper class. The one with the `@Override` annotation is the method which is actually getting overridden, and that method does not do anything. So nothing comes out of your mapper, and nothing goes into the reducer, and consequently there is no output.

Delete the `map` method marked with the `@Override` annotation and mark the first `map` method with `@Override`. Then fix any method signature issues, and it should work.

Comment: I was supposed to get each word and its frequency, but part-00000 just shows some numbers and it's frequency. Most of the times 1 as frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I resolved it by deleting the overrided map method and changing signature of map method with first argument to be of `LongWritable`. Update the map method signature as below:

```
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) 
    throws IOException {
```